# Refractoring Laravel 7 Factory to Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I am having a hard to figuring out how to refractor a factory in Laravel 7 to Laravel 8.  Below is the original factory in L7 and the L8 version below is the one I've tried refactoring.  I know the `$factory->define` is wrong and this is where I am stuck.

**Laravel 7 Version**

```
<?php

/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */

use App\Login;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(Login::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    $randomDateTime = $faker->dateTimeBetween('-6 hours', 'now');
    return [
        'user_id' => factory(App\User::class),
        'tenant_id' => factory(App\Tenant::class),
        'created_at' => $randomDateTime,
        'updated_at' => $randomDateTime,
    ];
});
```

**Laravel 8 Version**

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Login;
use App\Models\Tenant;
use App\Models\User;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;


$factory->define(Login::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    $randomDateTime = $faker->dateTimeBetween('-6 hours', 'now');
    return [
        'user_id' => User::factory(),
        'tenant_id' => Tenant::factory(),
        'created_at' => $randomDateTime,
        'updated_at' => $randomDateTime,
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options here:

## Use old factories

If you don't have the time for properly refactoring your factories, you can still use your old Laravel 7 factories by pulling in the `laravel/legacy-factories` package:

```sh
composer require laravel/legacy-factories
```

## Refactor your factories

Laravel 8 factories are now classes. Previously, you would call a define method on the `$factory` object, passing it the class and a closure that would return the factory definition like so:

```php
<?php

use App\User;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$factory->define(User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'email_verified_at' => now(),
        'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi',
        'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
    ];
});
```

In Laravel 8, the same would be written as follows and be put in `database/factories/UserFactory.php` for auto-discovery:

```php
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class UserFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->name(),
            'email' => $this->faker->unique()->safeEmail(),
            'email_verified_at' => now(),
            'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi',
            'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
        ];
    }
}
```

As you see, factories are now separate classes that extend from the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory` class.

Additionally, you need to use the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory` trait on the Model to allow the discovery of factories for the Model. Once you add this trait, Laravel expects a Factory class by the name of the Model, suffixed with `Factory` in the `database/factories` folder.

You can read up on all that in the [Defining Model Factories](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#defining-model-factories) chapter of the database testing documentation.

## In your specific case

The code you posted would need to be refactored and put in `database/factories/LoginFactory.php`:

```php
namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class LoginFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        $randomDateTime = $faker->dateTimeBetween('-6 hours', 'now');

        return [
            'user_id' => User::factory(),
            'tenant_id' => Tenant::factory(),
            'created_at' => $randomDateTime,
            'updated_at' => $randomDateTime,
        ];
    }
}
```

Then you need to `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;` in your `Login.php` model class and of course you would have do the same for the `User` and `Tenant` models, creating `UserFactory.php` and `TenantFactory.php`.